# Google AppEngine: How to redirect to html error page when error 403 occurs on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, google-cloud-platform, http-status-code-403

I'm looking for a way to redirect 403 errors to a html error page on AppEngine Standard Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: GCP is huge! Which component do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) file so it redirects errors to custom pages by using the [`error_handlers`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#error_handlers) element:

> **`error_handlers`:** Optional. Used to configure custom error pages that are returned for different error types.